# How can replace last character in string inside file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

How can i replace the last character in string by an X in file variable

I try this but doesn't work :

```
sed -i "s/EXTRA_VARIABLE/s/.$.X/$VAR_EXTRA/g" filename.txt
```

VAR_EXTRA=GTA

The filename.txt contain :

EXTRA_VARIABLE foo BEE

what i want is :

GTX foo BEE

The last charcter of VAR_EXTRA is replace by an X and EXTRA_VARIABLE  is replace by VAR_EXTRA  value (GTX)

Comment: Do you mean `sed -i "s/EXTRA_VARIABLE/EXTRA_VARIABLX/g" filename.txt`?

Comment: no i will update my post with details

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to do two substitutions

```
$ sed "s/EXTRA_VARIABLE/${VAR_EXTRA::-1}X/" file
```

1. replace the last char of a variable
2. replace a string in a file with the updated variable

first is done in `bash` string manipulation (delete the last char and append X), and the second is standard sed.